# Working with string (array?) of bits of an unspecified length

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm a javascript code monkey, so this is virgin territory for me.

I have two "strings" that are just zeros and ones:

```
var first =  "00110101011101010010101110100101010101010101010";
var second = "11001010100010101101010001011010101010101010101";
```

I want to perform a bitwise `&` (which I've never before worked with) to determine if there's any index where `1` appears in both strings.

These could potentially be VERY long strings (in the thousands of characters). I thought about adding them together as numbers, then converting to strings and checking for a `2`, but javascript can't hold precision in large intervals and I get back numbers as strings like `"1.1111111118215729e+95"`, which doesn't really do me much good.

Can I take two strings of unspecified length (they may not be the same length either) and somehow use a bitwise `&` to compare them?

I've already built the loop-through-each-character solution, but `1001^0110` would strike me as a major performance upgrade. Please do not give the javascript looping solution as an answer, this question is about using bitwise operators.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question, I wouldn't tell answerers that you're going to downvote them if they give a certain answer, especially if the answer may be the best answer

Comment: @scrblnrd3 except I get a lot of people suggesting completely unrelated answers when I go out on a limb with unusual applications of functionality - namely the "normal" workaround. Figured this was fair warning.

Comment: Still, though, is there a problem with using looping apart from that you asked a question about bitwise?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 No, looping would actually work for what I'm doing, and I've already done that. I'm looking for performance, my understanding is that bitwise operators are highly performant and at least look similar to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Alright. that makes sense. You might want to add that in your question  though

Comment: If you want to find where a `1` appears in both strings, shouldn't you be seeking to use a bitwise `AND`?

Comment: @JLRishe You are correct, updating question.

Comment: Most likely any performance gains you could achieve would be far outweighed by the cost of parsing the strings into numbers several hundred times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed yourself, javascript has limited capabilities if it's about integer values. You'll have to chop your strings into "edible" portions and work your way through them. Since the parseInt() function accepts a base, you could convert 64 characters to an 8 byte int (or 32 to a 4 byte int) and use an and-operator to test for set bits (`if (a & b != 0)`)

Comment: I would recommend benchmarking this to find out if it is actually faster than iterating through the characters. I have my doubts.

Comment: So do I. The original question excludes the looping method. Would be simple: take one string and iterate over it. As soon as you hit a "1", test the other string. The approach above will only be faster if the interpreter is very slow and the built in conversion functions are fast.

Comment: @JLRishe I will be benchmarking when I have the full functionality built out for my scenario. The conversion functions would definitely be the wildcard here - the actual matching should be significantly faster.

Comment: @Randy: Don't forget to publish the results. I'm curious :-)

Comment: @Ronald I'm still working on it, but due to the way I need the match to happen I don't think this will work in my specific extended scenario (I'd have to take 64 character chunks, one index at a time, and match them against the other string, in 64 character chunks, one index at a time, and move along each string). But if someone comes around looking, this answer sums up what's possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
var first = "00110101011101010010101110100101010101010101010010001001010001010100011111",
    second = "10110101011101010010101110100101010101010101010010001001010001010100011100",
    firstInt = parseInt(first, 2),
    secondInt = parseInt(second, 2),
    xorResult = firstInt ^ secondInt, //524288
    xorString = xorResult.toString(2); //"10000000000000000000"
```

Comment: This will not work if the strings are thousands of characters long, which the asker has stated as a requirement.